# Can a custom SharePoint 2013 web part act both as a consumer and a provider without the need for postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, webpart-connection

I am looking for a general method of implementing a web part that is both a consumer and a provider, without the need for an initial postback or redirect.
I need to establish whether this is theoretically possible, and if so, what the mechanism might be.

A colleague has mentioned the possibility of using the IConnectionData interface, but my searches have yielded little information about how this would work.

An example scenario might be that I have three custom textbox web parts (A, B and C), where B acts as both a provider and consumer.
A populates itself by running a query, and provides its current value to B.
B runs a query, passing the contents of textbox A as a parameter.
C runs a query, taking the contents of textbox B as a parameter.

The textboxes were used purely as an example. I might equally want to use the same mechanism to populate dropdowns or anything else that you can think of. I also need to be able to chain any number of web parts together.

My problem is that ConnectionProvider methods are always called before any ConnectionConsumer methods, so I do not have a way of A providing a value to B which then consumes it and then provides a value to C.

The key point is that multiple web parts need to be populated and chained before any user-interaction or postback occurs.

Comment: You can do this using Ajax and JQuery. No need t implement IConnectionData if its only one Web Part.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I am looking to develop a series of different web parts that can be chained together as desired A>B>C>D etc. (It should also be possible to connect multiple web parts to another web part eg. A>C and B>C, or A>C and B>C).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to get this working by making the web parts implement the IConnectionData interface. I had some doubts as to the approach, but it turned out that we just had some errors in our code.